# AngularJS how to use function from one controller in other controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create modular application in angularjs, I have two modules home and templates. how to use the functions of one module into the second module

**Module Home**

```
    angular.module('home',[]).controller('homeCtrl', function($scope){
         //this function to templatesModule
         $scope.useThisFunctionInTemplateCtrl = function(){}
    })
```

Module templates

```
    angular.module('templates',[]).controller('templatesCtrl', function($scope){
         //here function from homeCtrl
         $scope.functionFromhomeCtrl = function(){}
    })
```

Main app.js

```
angular.module('myApp',['home', 'templates']);
```

Comment: You can use `$rootScope`

Comment: ... or consider using a service, if you wan't to share logic between controllers.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja $rootScope not working

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use your controllers as a class that other controllers inherit from. Instead, have your controllers require dependencies from services (like generic functions/classmethods)

Comment: This *feels like* an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  You have some unknown problem, and your attempted solution is to have one module call a function in a different module.  Not only does this break quite a few design principles (Open/Close, Single Responsibility, Dependency Inversion, etc.), it also doesn't make for a very clear question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  need a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) to share information between controllers:

```
angular.module('yourModule').factory('yourService', function(){
    var self = this;

    self.sharedFunction = function(){}

    return self;
})
```

And inject it in your controllers

```
angular.module('home',[]).controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, yourService){
     //this function to templatesModule
     $scope.useThisFunctionInTemplateCtrl = yourService.sharedFunction();
})
```

$rootScope is for storing global variables, it should be avoided otherwise.

Comment: The 'home' module depends on a service defined in the module named 'yourModule'. The dependency needs to be included: `angular.module('home', ['yourService']).controller...`.

Comment: Yes, if 'yourModule' is a new module it should be registered like `angular.module('yourModule', [/*dependencies*/])`, and should be included as `angular.module('home',['yourModule'])`, or he could inject it into `myApp` to make it available for every other module.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not the good practice, but fulfills your need.

You can access functions over `controllers` using `$rootScope`.

Read more from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

**Home Controller:**

```
    angular.module('home',[]).controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){
         //this function to templatesModule
         $rootScope.useThisFunctionInTemplateCtrl = function(){}
    })
```

**Another Controller:**

```
angular.module('templates',[]).controller('templatesCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){
     //here function from homeCtrl
     $rootScope.useThisFunctionInTemplateCtrl(); //from another controller
     $scope.functionFromhomeCtrl = function(){}
})
```

Comment: while this would actually work, there are numerous reasons that this kind of practice should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

**1. Creating and Using AngularJS Service:**

Here is an complete example of how to create an AngularJS Service and use the AngularJS Service Mehtod in different Controllers:

```
//AngularJS Module

var app = angular.module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])

//AngularJS Route Config

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.caseInsensitiveMatch = true;
    $routeProvider.when("/products/details/:id",
    {
        templateUrl: "Temaplates/details.html",
        controller: "productDetailsController"
    })
     .when("/products/edit/:id",
    {
        templateUrl: "Temaplates/edit.html",
        controller: "productEditController"
    })

// AngularJS Service

app.factory('productService', function ($http, $routeParams) {
      return {
          getDataById: function () {
              //return promise from here
              return $http.get("http://localhost:43618/api/Products", {
                  params: { id: $routeParams.id }
              });
          }
      };
  });

// AngularJS Controllers Where Service Method has been used

app.controller("productDetailsController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, productService) {
     $scope.message = "Product Details";
     productService.getDataById().then(function (response) {
         $scope.product = response.data;
     }, function (error) {
         console.log("Error occured ", error);
     });
});

.controller("productEditController", function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, productService) {
    $scope.message = "Edit Page";
    $scope.product = {};

    productService.getDataById().then(function (response) {
        $scope.product = response.data;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error occured ", error);
    });

   $scope.updateProduct = function (product) {
        $http({
            method: "PUT",
            url: "http://localhost:43618/api/Products",
            params: { id: $routeParams.id },
            data: product
        })
        .success(function () {
            alert("Product Updated Successfully");
            $location.path('/products');
        });
    }

})
```

**2. Using rootScope Object**

But There is a problem using rootScope object and that is: Whenever you refresh your page rootScope object will be lost.

**So it always better to use AngularJS Service over rootScope**